# How can I bs4 import from BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

**I'm facing this problem even though i follow the system down so can anyone tell me where is the actually in it and what is the way to fix it**

Comment: what do you exactly want to do? `pip install beautifulsoup4`? or `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`. Programming is a process where you face problems and learn to overcome them. And when you go [here](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) you see it in the first line of quickstart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first install beautifulsoup4

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

then import

```
from bs4 import beautifulsoup
```